Snapping verticies to nearest vertex in QGIS
In QGIS, I have a layer with multiple polygon features that are near to each other. In this case, the features are regions on a map.
How do I get the vertices on one polygon feature to automatically snap to the nearest vertex on the other polygon features, to cause all polygon regions to exactly share borders with adjacent polygon regions?

Look at the snap geometries to layer tool.  Another option is to use v.grass and set a snap tolerance but you should read up on using GRASS tools first.
